# I have getting this error in API calling "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established"

Tags: flutter, dart

I have getting this error on API calling, please help me

Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Comment: are you facing error in android or iOS device ?

Answer (score 0):

possible solution (if you are using windows OS), is to follow the process below:

Press the Windows Key
Search For Internet Options

Click on "Internet Options"

Click On "Connection"

Go to LAN Settings

Uncheck "Use Proxy Server for LAN ...."

It should work but the permanent solution is to make sure you turn all software that might be automatically setting up proxy for you.

Comment: I have using Mac system please let me know some steps

Comment: I have using Mac system  and run app in emulator so can I changes for emulator device?